# How to know how many selected files in opendialog in c#?

Tags: c#, file, multi-select, opendialog

How to know how many files selected in opendialog in c# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.FileNames will probably hold the count of selected items :)

Answer (score 3):

[FileDialog.FileNames Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames.aspx)

> Gets the file names of all selected files in the dialog box.

For example

```
foreach (String myfile in openFileDialog1.FileNames) 
{
  // here myfile represent your selected file name 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms, check out the OpenFileDialogs `FileNames` property, which will hold all the selected files. In WPF, use the `Files` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
 {
 openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
 }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
 if (result == DialogResult.OK)
 {
 List<string> fff = openFileDialog1.FileNames.ToList();
 // Do something with the list
 }  
 }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: "Do something with the list", e.g. int X = fff.Count, which gives the number of the selected files in openFileDialog.

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim files() as String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(od.SelectedPath)
Dim Count as string = files.Length
```

Comment: Thsi will get you the number of files in the folders, not the number of files selected by the user.

Comment: this works if you are using FolderBrowserDialog. if you use OpenFileDialog u can get the files with op.FileNames